# Open plotly html file from script Python/R

Tags: python, r, plotly, r-plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly graph stored in a html file, `file.html`. This was created in another script using for example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.write_html('file.html', auto_open=True)
```

Is there a way to open directly the `html` file without rewrite the plotly code?
Something like:

```
fig = go.read_html('file.html')
```

I need the plot inside the variable. For example this has to work:

```
fig = read html file file.html
fig.write_html('copyOfFile.html', auto_open=True)
```

I use both Python and R so I'd like a solution for both/one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python standard library webbrowser. It uses default browser to open the document.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('file.html')
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain in a good way. I need the plot in a variable. webbrowser open the figure externally (or can I store it in a variable? I think it returns a boolean).

Comment: What do you want to do after you store it in a variable. Why not use `fig` as is?

Comment: Because I don't have the code used to generate the plot. I only have the output file file.html.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that.